# Allow new value on QuickPick in a VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to display to the user an input with some options, but the user can answer a new one.
Using `showQuickPick` I can show some options, but if the user answer a different option the return is `undefined`.

It's possible to do what I want?

I have already think about create a *New* option and then show an `InputBox` to the user, but I don't want that the user need to answer two questions.

Answer (score 3):

I have used a solution where **I inject the user input in the list of items**.
It works pretty well:

```js
const choices = ['a', 'b']

async function getUserSelectdValue() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const quickPick = window.createQuickPick();
        quickPick.items = choices.map(choice => ({ label: choice }));

        quickPick.title = 'Choose your favorite value:'

        quickPick.onDidChangeValue(() => {
            // INJECT user values into proposed values
            if (!choices.includes(quickPick.value)) quickPick.items = [quickPick.value, ...choices].map(label => ({ label }))
        })

        quickPick.onDidAccept(() => {
            const selection = quickPick.activeItems[0]
            resolve(selection.label)
            quickPick.hide()
        })
        quickPick.show();
    })
}
```

Please let me know if you need further explanations

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be interested in the approach taken in this issue?

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/89601